# Polynomials related to matrix

Tags: matrices, polynomials

Since I am a mechanical engineer, my background in finite field theory is weak (non-existent, basically). Recently, I started using MCMC methods to simulate stuff. I started digging and the algorithms to create the Markov chains need a uniform distribution sampler. The uniform distribution samplers are generally in the form of some PRNG.
I ended up at this paper.

- George Marsaglia and Liang-Huei Tsay, [Matrices and the Structure of Random Number Sequences](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82575488.pdf)

My question is related to the proof of Theorem $1$.

> The set $P$: all polynomials in $T$ of degree < $t$

I really don't know how that set would look like. Is it related to the minimal polynomial of $T$? If so, how?

I know that it would be composed of polynomials whose coefficients would be in the finite field (basically $1$'s or $0$'s). Thanks!

Comment: I know what the degree of a polynomial is, maybe it is a language barrier but I don't get the "in" part... what does a polynomial need to be "in" a matrix?

Comment: Oh, I see!  For example $P(T)=I+T+T^3$ is a "polynomial "in" T in the same way as $P(x)=1+x+x^3$ is a polynomial "in" (variable) $x$ ('"in" being synonym of "of").

Comment: You may be interested by this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3506925) of mine by the rotating drum problem and the illustration below.

Comment: Jean Marie, thank you, you just saved me a lot of time.

Comment: Pleasure. I appreciate. Too few people say thank you...